# converting table into css

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new to CSS and I wish to convert this table into CSS:

```html
<table dir="ltr" width="500" border="0" align="center">
    <caption><font face="Helvetica">Movies</font></caption>
    <colgroup width="50%" />
    <colgroup id="colgroup" class="colgroup" align="center" 
            valign="middle" title="title" width="1*" 
            span="2" style="background:#ddd;" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!--th scope="col">Artwork</th>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
            <th scope="col">Genre</th>
            <th scope="col">Format</th>
            <th scope="col">Year</th -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><font face="Georgia"><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-AGAaic1-yrM/TcWmj77lHzI/AAAAAAAAAkQ/K6zzSk1WgUY/s1600/thor-movie-poster-1.jpg" alt="Thor" width="175" height="200"/><br/>THOR<br/>Action<br/>DVD<br/>2011</td>
            <td align="center"><font face="Georgia"><img src="http://www.galacool.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/hangover2.jpg" alt="Hangover" width="175" height="200"/><br/>Hangover<br/>Comedy<br/>DVD<br/>2009</td>
            <td align="center"><font face="Georgia"><img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_E5cSkRNNzuk/TBxZ20kWzTI/AAAAAAAAJAk/Xo6O12VdYgA/s1600/ToyStory3aa.jpg" alt="Toy Story 3" width="175" height="200"/><br/>Toy Story 3<br/>Animation<br/>DVD<br/>2010</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><font face="Georgia"><img src="http://www.dvdactive.com/images/news/screenshot/2011/6/insidious2d.jpg" alt="Insidious" width="175" height="200"/><br/>Insidious<br/>Horror<br/>DVD<br/>2010</td>
            <td align="center"><font face="Georgia"><img src="http://www.femalefirst.co.uk/image-library/port/376/1/127-hours-dvd.jpg" alt="127 Hours" width="175" height="200"/><br/>127 Hours<br/>Drama<br/>DVD<br/>2010</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there any guides or links to do this?

Additionally, I will be importing these images from MySQL as well as the movie's title, year, genre, etc. How do I make this simpler for me by using CSS?

Comment: How about `table` --> `div`s? ;)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck using CSS? Also, this looks like a *good use* for a table for once (though not a good table), since it's *tabular data*.

Comment: This isn't really tabular data. It's `<table>` being used for layout!

Comment: @Michael: A table would be appropriate if it was being displayed as tabular data, but the table is being used for grid layout.

Comment: @icktoofay, I have seen light, and hereby retract my comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like that's a list of movies, so you could start by turning it into an unordered list:

```html
<ul class="grid">
    <li>
        <p class="image"><img src="..." alt="movie picture" /></p>
        <p class="name">Movie 1</p>
        <p class="genre">Action</p>
        <p class="format">DVD</p>
        <p class="year">2010</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="image"><img src="..." alt="movie picture" /></p>
        <p class="name">Movie 2</p>
        <p class="genre">Romance</p>
        <p class="format">DVD</p>
        <p class="year">2011</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

With that, you could then apply a style on the list:

```css
ul.grid, ul.grid > li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.grid {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
ul.grid > li {
    width: 175px;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

**See a demo (with slightly more styles to match your old table-based HTML) [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfYcr/).**

Comment: You shouldn't bother with wrapping the img in a paragraph and just make it block instead, don't need an extra class to identify it either... Paragraphs for the rest may not be what you should be using either (not very semantic, they're not real paragraphs are they?).

Comment: @sg3s: It's true. I was thinking about letting about the `img` just be a block, but I thought it might be a little more consistent for it to be like the others. Additionally, you're correct about the paragraphs. I was thinking about using a definition list, but I was thinking that might be a bit verbose.

Comment: @icktoofay Hi thanks for your code, I have a question.. How do I make sure that this grid will always be 3 columns and 2 rows only?

Comment: @exxcellent: Add `width: 540px;` and `height: 600px;` to `ul.grid`. Then add `height: 300px;` to `ul.grid > li`. You may want to adjust the width; it has to be bumped up from `175 * 3` to account for the width of the scrollbar. You may also want to play with the heights; I just rounded the current automatically-determined height to the nearest 100 pixels.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you want to convert this?

I wouldn't convert this information.  It looks like data suited to a table.

When you have content that is best organized in columns and rows, it probably should be presented in a table.

When seen on the screen, it looks like formatting.  However, at one point, you did have these headers on your page:

```
    <th scope="col">Artwork</th>
    <th scope="col">Title</th>
    <th scope="col">Genre</th>
    <th scope="col">Format</th>
    <th scope="col">Year</th>
```

What are you trying to achieve?

If you are compiling a listing and would like to **compare** the info, I still think a table is best.

However, if you are using this as a display for videos that you are selling or renting, then check our @icktoofay's response.

Comment: Try the HTML. It's not tabular data. It's a grid of items.

Comment: I deleted my earlier comment since you've added a bit more to your answer and it looks more like an answer now than a comment.